# How do I set a custom path in textmate to find my ruby files?

Tags: ruby, textmate

I'm new to programming and trying to learn Ruby through some online tutorials. I have textmate and have created a Ruby folder in my Documents folder to hold my .rb files. While working through "Why's Poignant Guide" I came a across a two file program. One file attempts to 'require' the other. However, this doesn't work in this folder. Is there anyway to set textmate up to look here. I've come across a few sites that seem to be addressing this but I don't understand how file paths work in Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set the `RUBYLIB` variable to the directory that contains your files. Let's say it's at `~/Documents/Ruby` (that is, a folder "Ruby" in your "Documents" folder). `~` is shorthand for `/User/yourusername`, so the full path to the directory is `/Users/yourusername/Documents/Ruby`. You'll set this as `RUBYLIB` in TextMate, which you can do by going to Preferences -> Advanced -> Shell Variables, then click the "+" button and add `RUBYLIB` as the "Variable" and `/Users/yourusername/Documents/Ruby` as the "Value".

Comment: Thanks for the response mipadi. This still isn't working. No idea why. Running an old iBook with 10.5.8. Frustrating but I'll work around it for now I guess.